# How to enable CORS in Nginx proxy server to allow react app access Yii2 rest API resource?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, yii2, cors

I'm building a react app which access api running on nginx server, in dev mode on local host i enable proxy by adding api server url to the proxy option in package.json file in react and everything works fine, now I move to production mode and I have an error resulting from CORS after making some research I came up with the following:

nginx conf file for my target API server:

```
server {
     set $project_root /var/www/html/example.com;
     set $root /usr/share/nginx/html;
     charset utf-8;
     client_max_body_size 128M;
     server_name api.example.com;
     #access_log /data/wwwlogs/access_nginx.log combined;
     root $project_root/api/web;
     index index.html index.htm index.php;
     #error_page 404 /404.html;
     #error_page 502 /502..html;
     error_page 503 /api_maintenance_on.html;
    
    location = /api_maintenance_on.html {
        root $root/;
    }

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://example.com';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
    
     location / {
     
        if (-f $root/api_maintenance_on.html) {
            return 503;
        }
         rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$args&request_filename=$1 last;
         try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
         
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
          add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;
          add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
          add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
          return 204;
        }

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-real-ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-forward-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://example.com;
     }

}
```

after adding the above to my conf file the below URL start working without error:

```
https://api.example.com/v1/helpers/get-currency-rate?=$
```

But other URL still not working still showing below error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/v1/auth/login' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I use axios to make remote API call and below is my axios configuration:

```
import axios from 'axios';
const BASE_URL = 'https://api.example.com';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    withCredentials: true
});

export const axiosPrivate = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    withCredentials: true
});
```

Below is also my PHP script using YII2 rest controller

```
class HelpersController extends \yii\rest\ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = '';
   
    
    public function behaviors() {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => \sizeg\jwt\JwtHttpBearerAuth::class,
            'except' => [
                'get-currency-rate',
            ],
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }

    public function actionGetCurrencyRate($currency){
        
          $selectedCurrency = empty($currency) || !isset($currency) || $currency == "" ? "₦" : 
          $currency;
        return ['currency' =>$cur, 'rate'=> $rate];
    }
    
}

class AuthController extends \yii\rest\ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\UserRefreshToken';
    
    public function behaviors() {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => \sizeg\jwt\JwtHttpBearerAuth::class,
            'except' => [
                'login',
                'options',
            ],
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }

     public function actionLogin() {
        $model = new LoginForm();
        $custom = new Custom();
        
        
        
        return $message;
    }

}
```

Before I made changes to my nginx server config both controller were not accessible throwing CORS error but after making the above changes to my server congif file Helpers Controllers was accessible without CORS error but Auth controller still throw CORs error

How do I solve this problem or where exactly the problem is coming from?

Comment: For one thing, you cannot use the wildcard for credentialed requests: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Comment: @jub0bs Access-Control-Allow-Headers value has been updated from wildcard to the following but still didn't solve the error. "Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range"

Comment: In your example, what is the domain name of the FE application - in both successful and failed cases are they the same?

Comment: @user11666461 checking the request header in both cases the domain name remain the same https://example.com, both request were sent from the same domain name in both success and failed cases